# Xrandr does not recognize newmode option

Tags: xrandr

I was trying to modify the screen resolution using xrandr. I used the following command.

```
xrandr -s 1680x1050
```

It returned an error.

```
size 1680x1050 not found in available modes
```

I figured I have to define and add the mode.

```
cvt 1680 1050
```

worked. After that I tried to add new mode

```
xrandr --newmode <model-line>
```

Here the newmode option is not recognized. The command does not go through.

```
usage: xrandr [options]
 where options are 
-display
-help. etc.
```

And the --newmode option is not even listed there.

Answer (score 1):

Check the RandR version with this command:

> xrandr -v

It might say something like this :

> Server reports RandR version 1.1

xrandr is a command line interface to the RandR extension. The "--newmode" is not supported in RandR version 1.1.